# Why is the flutter MediaQuery starting from top of the screen

Tags: flutter

When I am using the MediaQuery to resize a container, like this  =>

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
```

the subtraction or the resizing of the container starts from the bottom instead of from the top. Please someone should help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap it with `Align`. It happens because naturally Flutter draw the Widgets from Top Left.

Something like this:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
),
```

Comment: thank you @FederickJonathan your answer really helped me out, again thank you.

Comment: @august You are welcome. If you find an answer is helpful, give it a check mark so other people know this post already has a correct answer. Cheers~

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the answer by [@FederickJonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59780035/8112679),

`Align` gives you some default positions to  align your widget as described here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment-class.html#constants

But you can also customize the position.

However you like, by giving Alignment as `Alignment(X, Y)`.

X = -1.0 - 1.0, starting from left->right

Y = -1.0 - 1.0, starting from top->bottom

**Fun fact**:
Not Just `flutter` but almost all Rendering framework which paints the screen to display your views always starts from the Top-Left corner of the screen.

It is known as the origin point of the view/screen.

In flutter, if no co-ordinates or alignment is provided, then you'll see that the view is plotted starting from the top left corner.

The Origin point is also considered as the source of `Light` in material design. So all the shadows are cast to the bottom to the right side initially.

**Update**: Material Design [combines various light sources for shadow](https://material.io/design/environment/light-shadows.html#light). So the above fact is not true for material design but still you can see it in some other design guide lines.

Comment: thank you @HarshvardhanJoshi for your contribution, at least now i have a better knowledge of using alignment.